# Explain behaviour in a recursive method alternative to a For Loop

Tags: java, functional-programming

Here is a piece of code I debuged but I can't see how it works:

```
    int[] miArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    System.out.println(arraySum2(miArray, 0));

    public static int arraySum2(final int[] array, final int start) {
    if (start >= array.length) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return array[start] + arraySum2(array, start + 1);
    }
}
```

From start values of 0 to 5 the else run, but when 5 is reached the return instead of returning 0, it starts going through the else and adding the numbers and the start var begins decreasing. Why? It should return 0 as it says, right?

Yes, it is supposed to do that, but I do not see how it works and a clear explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: `arraySum2(array, 5)` returns zero. `arraySum2(array, 4)` returns `array[4] + arraySum2(array, 5)`, which is `5 + 0`. Follow the logic. This is how recursion works.

Comment: Thanks, but i can not follow the logic. I can`t find the logic. I do not get you. Thanks anyway for trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `array` is `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }`:

- `arraySum2(array, 0)` returns `array[0] + arraySum(array, 1)`
- `arraySum2(array, 1)` returns `array[1] + arraySum(array, 2)`
- `arraySum2(array, 2)` returns `array[2] + arraySum(array, 3)`
- `arraySum2(array, 3)` returns `array[3] + arraySum(array, 4)`
- `arraySum2(array, 4)` returns `array[4] + arraySum(array, 5)`
- `arraySum2(array, 5)` returns `0`.

OK. So now knowing what `arraySum2(array, 5)` evaluates to, we can work out what `arraySum2(array, 4)` returns, and so on:

- `arraySum2(array, 5)` is `0`
- so `arraySum2(array, 4)` will be `array[4] + 0  == 5 + 0  == 5`
- so `arraySum2(array, 3)` will be `array[3] + 5  == 4 + 5  == 9`
- so `arraySum2(array, 2)` will be `array[2] + 9  == 3 + 9  == 12`
- so `arraySum2(array, 1)` will be `array[1] + 12 == 2 + 12 == 14`
- so `arraySum2(array, 0)` will be `array[0] + 14 == 1 + 14 == 15`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I see it now, but one more question: In the IF..Else, when it reaches start=5, it should just return 0 (end of the story), not the result of the the other stuff. Why?

Comment: Why StackOverflow does not like that this kind of questions get solved? (-3?) Come'on recursive is not easy when you are learning it. THANK YOU VERY KIND. Really kind!

Comment: When `return 0` is executed, that is the end of `arraySum2(array, 5)`. But `arraySum2(array, 4)` is still waiting to return `array[4] + arraySum(array, 5)`. Once it gets that 0 back, it can add it to `array[4]` giving its own return value. Each call to `arraySum2` will execute its own return statement and return its own correct value.